# How to open file from URI?

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to crate, a file uploader fragment.

First of all, user picks up files, and after that I show the picked up files in a recycler view.

If the user clicks to recyclerView item, I would like to open the file.

So it is the problem, I tried a lot of answer, but I can't solve this.

I tried to open specific files for example pdf, and the pdf reader is opened, but couldn't find the file, and it happened when I want to open image fil as well

In the feature, when it is works, I would like to save and open different files for exaple images, documents etc

minSdk : 19
target: 30

```
onActivityResult: 
 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    data?.let { it ->
                        var list = mutableListOf<DocumentView>()

                        if (it.clipData != null) {
                            for (i in 0 until it.clipData!!.itemCount) {
                                it.clipData?.getItemAt(i)?.uri?.let { uri ->
                                    viewModel.selectedFilesUri.add(uri)
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            it.data?.let { uri ->
                                viewModel.selectedFilesUri.add(uri)

                                getFileMetaData(uri)?.let { documentView ->
                                    list.add(documentView)
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        refreshFileList()
                    }
                }

    private fun refreshFileList(){
        val uris = viewModel.selectedFilesUri
        val list = mutableListOf<DocumentView>()

        uris.forEach { uri->
            getFileMetaData(uri)?.let {
                list.add(it)
            }
        }

        adapter.submitList(list)
    }

    private fun openFile(documentView: DocumentView, uri: Uri) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(uri,"application/pdf")
        startActivity(intent)
    }

Manifest Provider: 
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_path" />
        </provider>

file_path:
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: Add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cited your code as being from `onActivityResult()`. My guess is that you are using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, or perhaps `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, with `startActivityForResult()`, to get your `Uri` values.

[You have rights to access that content from the `Activity` that received the result](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html). Anything else needs to be granted permission. That includes third-party apps that you start via `ACTION_VIEW`.

Adding `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` extends your read access rights to the content to whatever `ACTION_VIEW` activity winds up being started.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it this way easier

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_PERMISSION);
```